# Remove ifupdown(eth0) connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, 14.04, pppoe

While I was installing Ubuntu 14.04 I had some issues with graphic card drivers so I needed to install drivers from root, I created adsl connection using pppoeconf.
Now when I boot up my PC I have two connections, my regular connection which I use and `ifupdown(eth0)` which was created using `pppoeconf`.

How can I delete `eth0` connection so it doesn't bothers me anymore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your file manager and go to /etc/network/. Once there, you have to edit the file **interfaces** like this:

```
  sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

or

```
  gksu mousepad /etc/network/interfaces
```

and delete all entries in there except for **auto lo / iface lo inet loopback**.

The following lines

```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
```

have to be the only entries present in /etc/network/interfaces.

Next you should edit a second file located in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. Use this code in a terminal window:

```
   sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

or

```
   gksu mousepad /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Look for this entry **[ifupdown]** and edit the entry to look like this:

```
   [ifupdown]
   managed=false
```

Reboot and reconfigure if necessary your network using the network applet from system tray.

Comment: It didn't work. It hid the connections in network manager instead. And instead of `lo` I had `eno1` ininterfaces. I am using 16.04

Answer (score 8):

Open terminal and enable super user mode.

```
nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

The contents of the file will be like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq  
[ifupdown]  
managed=true
```

Please change the plugins section to:

```
plugins=keyfile,ofono
```

Restart the network manager:

```
service network-manager restart
```

It worked for me, I hope it will work or you too.

Comment: It worked for me. Howevever I set the managed to false as it was so before.