# How can I restore my broken (appears to be renamed) wired ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, network-manager, ethernet

Yesterday I lost my internet connection after rebooting my Ubuntu 16.04 installation. Now when Ubuntu boots, it searches for a network for a couple of minutes, then states "Connection established" but I can't get online or communicate (send ping requests, for instance) to anyone.

I deleted the ethernet network, hoping it would re-initialize if I re-added it. When I click the network manager icon, the "Ethernet Network" is greyed out (so I can't enable it). There is a new entry now, called "Auto Ethernet" but that one doesn't work (same symptoms as I mentioned earlier).

If I try to add a new ethernet network connection, the "eth0" is gone from the list of devices. Instead, I now have a "eno1" entry which I've never seen before. It might be the same device that is renamed but I don't know.

My /etc/network/interfaces file contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Is there some way of re-installing my network manager and/or ethernet driver without network connection? Or am going to have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Your network interface was named differently because, as of 16.04, interface names adhere to a standard called "Predictable Network Interface Names" described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). However, your `/etc/network/interfaces` ought to contain a line `auto eno1` followed by either a `dhcp` line or a description of a static IP address.

Comment: Added "eno1" entry to /etc/network/interfaces: auto eno1 iface eno1 inet dhcp. Still, same error

Comment: Did you `sudo systemctl restart networking`?

Comment: Tried that now, it seemed to just hang forever. Rebooted a couple of times. Tried "sudo ifdown eno1" just to try to re-enable the device or whatever. It hung at "waiting for lock" for a while. Rebooted some more. Suddenly, my connection works again.

Comment: I tried to remove the eno1 entry in /etc/network/interfaces, rebooted and it is now working. However, the entries in my network manager dropdown are "Ethernet Network"(greyed out), "Auto Ethernet"(enabled). Is ther "Ethernet Network" broken, and replaced by "Auto Ethernet"? Why are there two entries there when I only have one (the "Auto Ethernet") in my network manager window?

Comment: I believe those correspond to entries in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. You can delete those, they will be recreated if necessary.

Comment: Removed the file "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Auto\ Ethernet", re-added the eno1 entry to /etc/network/interfaces and rebooted. Now I have no network connections in the network manager, but I'm connected and online ... ? See this pic: http://i.imgur.com/U2MOWYA.png

Comment: "device not managed" - open `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, change `managed=false` to `managed=true`, and restart NetworkManager.

Comment: Okay, did that now. Now my network manager lists two connections: "eno1" and "Ifupdown (eno1)". See this pic: http://i.imgur.com/unRpdrH.png. I really appreciate you helping me, by the way.

Comment: Also, the answer in this thread seems to disagree a little with your approach: http://askubuntu.com/questions/455736/remove-ifupdowneth0-connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39719/discussion-between-jos-and-birger-skogeng-pedersen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer summarizes the chat:

You can either:

- let NetworkManager take care of network connections; make sure that `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Restart the Network Manager after changes: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`. Obsolete entries in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` can be deleted; if necessary, they will be recreated.
- do away with NetworkManager altogether, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455736/remove-ifupdowneth0-connection). In this case, the file `/etc/networking/interfaces` is decisive.

The fact that your network interface was renamed has to do with `systemd` adhering to a standard called "Predictable Network Interface Names" described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).